# Why are verbs following "have not" in past tense, but verbs following "did not" are in present tense?

Tags: tense, negation, infinitives, auxiliary-verbs, tense-agreement

For example:

> I have not booked the flight.
>   I did not book the flight.
>
> I haven't bought the lemons.
>   I did not buy the lemons.

Comment: They're not! In your examples, the verbs "booked" and "bought" that follow the perfect auxiliary "have" are past-participles, not past tense forms, though for most verbs the forms are identical. "Did" is an auxiliary verb here that requires a plain (infinitival) verb-form like "book" and "buy" in you examples

Answer (score 3):

They're not in present or past tense. "Do", like most auxiliaries, is followed by the infinitive (the basic form of the verb): "Did you see him? I didn't see him". "Have" is followed by the past participle to form a perfect construction: "Have you seen him? I haven't seen him". 
The other anomalous auxiliary is "be", which can be followed by *either* the present participle for a progressive aspect, ("He was painting") *or* a past participle for a passive ("It was painted").